# How to access a series MultiIndex values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a multindex like so:

```
type         A     B
baseline    10    20
      date 
1960-11-09  11   100  
1960-11-10  20   505
1960-11-11  27   403
```

And I need to substract `baseline` from the values.

So I'm trying to iterate over the whole thing, get the vale for baseline and substract it:

```
while n < df.shape[1]:
    data = df.iloc[:,n]
    baseline = data.columns.get_level_values('baseline')
    # Probably some line to turn baseline from an Index to a float
    df.iloc[:,n] = data - baseline
    n += 1
```

But this fails with

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

whereas I'd expect to get something like

```
Index([10], dtype='object', name='baseline')
```

as I'm used to from using this on dataframes.

But if I run `data = df.iloc[:,n].head()` in isolation, I apparently still have my whole MultiIndex attached to the series. But how do I access it, now that it has apparently become a series?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate at all? `baseline = df.columns.get_level_values("baseline")` followed by `df.loc[:, (slice(None), baseline)] = df.loc[:, (slice(None), baseline)] - baseline` should work, no?

Comment: I've added a bit a about the outcome I'd expect from dataframes. And I'm trying to iterate since that seems to be the most obvious and easy to use solution to me. `slice(None)` isn't exactly intuitive to me. Also, it appears not to work for my real example when I try your suggestion.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,n]` is of course a 1D series because `n` makes the second dimension gone. In addition, honestly, I still couldn't understand what is your expected output....